# Copy csv from remote sftp server copy to my server's wordpress directory

Tags: php, wordpress, sftp

I'm looking for a solution to how I can copy a csv file that is on a remote sftp server and have it available on my server. I'm then using a plugin to pull the data from this csv into my wordpress database.

I have tried to do this with this PHP script:
https://phpseclib.com/docs/sftp

Do I need to install something on my server to get this running? Sorry, but I'm not very backend and a bit of a noob. There's probably a way easier approach to this..

I get a 500 error when I run this PHP file in the browser.

```
<?php
function getData(){
    use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;

    $sftp = new SFTP('server-domain', port); //default port is 22

    if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
        throw new Exception('Login failed');
    }

    $sftp->get(‘remote-server-file.csv’, 'my-server-file.csv' ); // return content of the file
    getData();
?>
```

Comment: Start by finding out what caused the 500 error. Look in the server error log.

Comment: This line here is causing the 500: use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;